# <Java> Can I use more than one Server Socket in TCP-IP?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

My homework is to make a very simple comic app using TCP-IP protocol, and I have to do two things:

1. send request to server side to get *all the comics in database*.
2. after that, I choose one of them and send another request to get *all the chapters of the comic I've chosen*.

I used two different server sockets and it worked well, but I don't know if it's right. Can (or must) I do it with only one server socket?

Comment: You certainly can. If you must? Ask your teacher.

Comment: Why two servers? That's be a massive pain the butt - imagine if every single page on a website required its own DEDICATED webserver. you set up a simple communications protocol, so you can send different commands to the server. e.g. a `getAllComics` command, which responds with the list of commands, then `getChaptersForComic=XXX`

Answer (score 0):

You can have in one application the following cases:

Only one server binded to a HostPort
or many different instances of servers each one binded to a different port..

the real question is Do you really need that??

It would be better maybe to design another strategy ??

Answer (score -3):

You cannot connect a socket to it self. Think about socket (TCP) like a server and a client. One has to connect to another. The server can't do connections and the client needs a server to connect to.